# EmberJS how to invoke transition before data load?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have simple CRUD app. When I move between listings, at first view load, and then ember-data load data from server. But when I click **link-to** to "edit" page, ember data start loading data from server, but view is **freezed**, and when data is loaded, view change.

How can I go to page at first, and then load other data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with the data being asynchronous, you can move the fetching of the data out of the model hook and into some other mechanism (which blocks the transition from completing).

Where you should fetch the data is then up to you, depending on the data being fetched my response is different.